# Passing parameters from controller to a view in a php mvc pattern using extract()

Tags: php, model-view-controller, scope, extract

I was trying to understand a php MVC tutorial and i couldn't understand how parameters were passed from the controller to a newly created view using the 
`extract();`(see the Controller class below) to add them in the symbol table (i don't know what will be its scope) inside a function `render()` from the Controller class and then on that same function call the `require($view)` function to display the view inside which these extracted variables will be simply available for call with a `<?php echo $var; ?>` .
For me these extracted variables will be available only locally inside the function in which they were extracted ( it means the `render()` function). 
Is it because the require function was called in that same level that those extracted variables will be available inside the view ? Will the view share the same symbole table as the contoller? or will these variables be set to the global scope ?

```
<?php
class Controller{

    public $request;
    public $vars = array();

    function __construct($request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function render($view){

        extract($this->vars);

        $view = ROOT.DS.'view'.DS.$this->request->controller.DS.$view.'.php';

        require($view); 

    }
    public function set($key,$value=null){
        if(is_array($key)){
                $this->vars += $key;
        }else{
                $this->vars[$key] = $value;
        }

    }


}

?>
```

PagesController.php in which the render() function will be called :

```
<?php
class PagesController extends Controller{

        function view($nom){


            $this->set(array('phrase' => 'Salut ',
                             'nom' => 'Bohh')   
            );

            $this->render('index2');
        }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) imports variables into the symbol table of the current scope. Therefore the "extracted" variables are available from within the `render()` method.

[PHP docs on extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

> Import variables from an array into the current symbol table.

The focus hereby is on the word **current**.

---

The reason why the variables are available from within the file that is `required` is, that all language constructs regarding inclusion inherit the scope of the place from where the file was included.

[PHP docs state](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

---

Variables you introduce in the included file will also only be available in the current scope. However functions and classes won't. They will reside in the global scope.

---

> Will the view share the same symbole table as the contoller?

It will use the symbol table of the controllers `render()` method in your case.

Comment: a simple and clear answer for a simple question , thanks !, i just don't understand why it was downvoted.